# CSV: Undefined Offset -> Convert to XML

Tags: php, xml, csv, converters, offset

I have this CSV file: http://www.gamesdeal.com/media/feedgenerator/Gamekey.csv

And get this error with PHP:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 6 in

But the problem is that I can not create the CSV file by my self. It is from a store. So, I can't modify it... Does somebody knows how I can fix this error?

Here my code:

```
function csvToXML($inputFilename, $outputFilename, $delimiter = ','){

    // Open csv to read
    $inputFile = fopen($inputFilename, 'rt');

    // Get the headers of the file
    $headers = fgetcsv($inputFile, 0, $delimiter);

    // Create a new dom document with pretty formatting
    $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $doc->formatOutput = true;

    // Add a root node to the document
    $root = $doc->createElement('products');
    $root = $doc->appendChild($root);

    while (($row = fgetcsv($inputFile, 0, $delimiter)) !== false) {

        $container = $doc->createElement('product');

        foreach ($headers as $i => $header) {
              $child = $doc->createElement($header);
              $child = $container->appendChild($child);
              $value = $doc->createTextNode($row[$i]);
              $value = $child->appendChild($value);
        }
        $root->appendChild($container);
    }

$strxml = $doc->saveXML();
    $handle = fopen($outputFilename, 'w');
    fwrite($handle, $strxml);
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Does your input file have comma's within its data fields, rather than only as delimiters? You might need to add an enclosure type to your [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) call.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem:

```
header: products_price <tab> price_currency

data: 5.45 EUR (no tab between 5.45 and EUR)
```

So in the header there are 7 fields defined, but only 6 in the data (also most records don't have a EAN value, but there's a tab at the end, so that should be ok).

To fix this you could:

- read all the fields manually
- first replace `products_price <tab> price_currency` with `products_price price_currency` in the header
- remove `price_currency` from `$headers`
- or somehow let the parser know there are only 6 fields instead of 7

You probably have to correct the price field afterwards then.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. I tried to fix it but it is not working... My problem currently is to implement your idea.. - Could you maybe give me a short example? - Furthermore the delimiter is `"\t"`. You cannot see it here. But I give the function the delimiter `"\t"`. The normal delimiter is `","` if I do not give the function any delimiter.

Comment: For a first quick test you could edit the file manually - in the header combine the two price fields together like this: products_price_price_currency and see if that works fine. If not, try to see where you get an error - maybe print the lines (and remove the foreach loop then) and later the fields with the foreach loop.

Comment: Also, on line 4111 SD0006586, there is a tab in the products_name (before the `-`), so the fields will be shifted to the right (but that shouldn't break your code).

Comment: Also, most EAN values will be empty. I don't know if that could be a problem in the code (I don't know php, so I can't tell for sure). But maybe you'd want to check it anyway and avoid creating an empty node.

Comment: I will do that. Thank You! :D

Comment: @FrazeJr. I updated the answer a bit. If the above works, then you could remove `price_currency` from `$headers` before the loop, and maybe split the price-currency field yourself if needed.

Comment: I will try it! Thanks